# Hide UISearchBar of UISearchDisplayController

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have a tabbar based application, and `UInavigationcontroller` for every tab. In a `TabViewController`, I have implemented a `UIsegmentedcontrol`, `searchDisplayController` and uitableview. The navigationItems, tabledata are changed based on the segmentedcontrol select. And for a segment i have hidden the search bar. But when the searchbar is hidden, tableview first row does not respond to `didselectrowatindexpath`.

Here is my code,

In segment change action

```
- (void)indexDidChangeForSegmentedControl:(UISegmentedControl *)aSegmentedControl {
[self changeNavigationItems];

l.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",self.segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex];
if([segmentIndexesToHideSearchBar containsObject: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", self.segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex]])
{
    self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.hidden = YES;
    self.dataTable.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.dataTable.frame.size.width, self.dataTable.frame.size.height);
}
else
{
    self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.hidden = NO;
    self.dataTable.frame = CGRectMake(0, 44, self.dataTable.frame.size.width, self.dataTable.frame.size.height);
}
[self.dataTable reloadData];
```

}

Other codes are generic and other things are working correct.

Second problem is when i am getting back from a details view by clicking on a row, the change of frame of table is not kept. There is a space where searchbar was.

Waiting for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured that out. My first problem was the first click on tableview row did not respond. That was for i have mistaken `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` for `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath`. What a silly mistake and I suffered for hours...:(

The second problem was for I was writing the hiding and frame changing code in `viewDidLoad` function, I moved the code to `viewDidAppear` function. Now the codes are working properly.

Answer (score 6):

I guess this is not the correct approach, but it works for me :)
to make it hidden:

```
CGRect searchFrame = self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.frame;
searchFrame.size.height = 0;

self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.frame = searchFrame;
self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.hidden = YES;
```

To "reveal" it again:

```
searchFrame.size.height = 44;
self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.frame = searchFrame;
self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.hidden = NO;
```

I'm not sure if this works with autolayout, never tried it. (Also this is on Xcode < 5, iOS<7)

Comment: Thank you for your time, but my code hides searchbar perfectly. I have problem somewhere else. The first click does not respond on the tablecell and when the tableview gets back, it isn't keeping the changed frame after searchbar hiding.

Comment: Oh, I see your answer :) Stuff like that happens to me all the time :D, I'm glad you figured it out, and thanks for upvote :)

Comment: Not a bad solution.  I'm a bit wary of the hard-coded assumption of 44 points in the "reveal" code.  But, the "hide" code works just fine with iOS 7.

Comment: Works in iOS 7, a better hack is to save off the original CGRect somewhere.