# Permanently Hide UISearchDisplayController

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7, uisearchdisplaycontroller, searchdisplaycontroller

I'm trying to hide the searchDisplay controller attached to a UITableView in an iOS 7 Table View Controller.  I don't want to temporarily scroll it off the top; I want it to be completely disabled.

In my table view controller code (which, FWIW is set to grouped style [because of this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21224937/extra-cells-visible-after-results-from-uisearchdisplaycontroller/21607675?noredirect=1#comment32702568_21607675)), I've got:

`self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.hidden = YES;`

This does hide the search bar, but unfortunately results in a blank box sitting at the top of my table:

[image: Blank Search Bar Space Screenshot]

This blank will scroll off screen just like the search bar.  `self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.hidden = NO;` will bring back the search bar as expected.

I've tried to use suggestions from both the question and answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19026758/hide-uisearchbar-of-uisearchdisplaycontroller) to shift my table view 44 pixels up, which kind of works except it has the side effect of hiding the pull-to-refresh indicator at the top of my table.

I've also tried setting the frame of my search bar to have no height like so:

```
self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.tableView.frame.size.width, 0);
```

but this doesn't get rid of the blank space at the top of my table either.

How do I hide a the search bar from a UISearchDisplayController and actually make the space it would occupy collapse as if it wasn't there in the first place?

Comment: have you thought of checking if the search display is actually hidden? Something such as if(self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.hidden) { // make the frame = 0; } else { // make frame = 44} and then set the frame below that

Comment: I set the hidden property in a if-statement based on a standardUserDefaults value.  I did try setting the frame for the searchBar in the same if-statement while setting the hidden property; I still had the side effect of the missing pull-to-refresh indicator.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually dealt with this by chaining the app's behavior circumvent the conditions for this weird behavior.  I'm not sure if this behavior was ever fixed in later OS releases.